# How to achieve leadership notion using consumer group of kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

Requirement:
Module1 publish data and module2 consumes it.

Here I can have multiple instances of module2 in which one node should act as a leader and consume the data from the topic and process it and add it to its inmemory. This node has the responsibility to replicate its inmemory with the rest of the module2 instances which acts as a passive node. One of the requirement here is the processing order should remain same.

How to design this in Kakfa?
My thoughts are Module1 publish to sample_topic (having single partition) and each instance of module2 will use the consumer group name and subscribe to sample_topic. Since any instance of the same consumer group can receive a message the concept of leader is not available.

Is there any way to achieve the leadership concept? similar to how brokers work in kafka.

Comment: Are you using Kafka Streams? Have you looked at the interactive query or global KTable features of it?

Comment: No I am using directly Kafka. I will check the Kafka Streams..

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out in the question - this is not the default behavior of a consumer group.

A consumer group will distribute the partitions across each consumer and you will not receive the same messages.

What you seem to need is a way to manage `global state` i.e. you want all consumers to be aware of and have reference to the same data.

There might be a way to hack this with the consumer API - but what I would suggest you look into is the [Kafka Streams API](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/).

More specifically, within the Kafka Streams API there is [an interface](https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/GlobalKTable.html) called `GlobalKTable`:

> A `KTable` distributes the data between all running Kafka Streams
> instances, while a `GlobalKTable` has a **full copy of all data on each
> instance**.

You can also just have each consumer subscribe to the same topic from **individual consumer groups**, unless it is a requirement that the consumer group must be the same for scaling purposes.